# Problems adding help bundle to Mac app in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to add a help bundle into my Mac app and the help viewer just can't seem to find it.  I must be missing something.

Here is what I've done.

1: Created a help document in iWeb and exported it into a local desktop directory /Helpbook

2: Got a 16x16 png for an image and put it into /Helpbook  (icon_16x16.png)

3: Copied the help director into the lprog directories for base and for en (base language)

4: Added those directories into the project

- I know this worked because I'm seeing the (Base) and (English)
  indicators within Xcode

5: Added plist entry CFBundleHelpBookFolder and set it to 'Helpbook'

6: Added plist entry CFBundleHelpBookName and set it to 'TestHelpBuild Help'

[image]

7: Went into the index.html file for both the base and English lprog versions and added:

- meta name="AppleTitle" content=“TestHelpBuild Help">
- meta name="AppleIcon" content=“Helpbook/icon_16x16.png">
- dropped initial less than sign so you could see the tag in the post
- added them within the  tag along with another meta name
  generated by iWeb

[image]

8: Ran Help Indexer over both Helpdesk directories

- Got some errors but got a .helpindex file
- Not sure what to think about that
- Help Indexer didn't like the meta names added above
- Worked ok without them

Clicking on the app menu entry to bring up 'app-name Help' shows me a box with no topics.

[image]

Anybody have any idea as to what might be wrong or areas that I might review more closely?

Here is the directory structure of the skeleton app I'm writing...

[image: File structure of the app]

And here's the actual file structure via Finder...

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you restarted the Mac ? I remember this so etimes was necessary to update the system help system on pre Mav versions.

Comment: Tried that but unfortunately it didn't work.  It's like the help viewer is starting ok but just can't find my stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it to work and I'm not sure how.

First thing is that I made the folder name 'TestHelpBuild Help' and made sure the index file meta name was also 'TestHelpBuild Help'.  Then I put those two names into the plist and, lo, my help text appeared.

This meant deleting the help folder out of the app, copying the new folder into the .lprog folders, and then re-adding it back into the app via Xcode.

If you're having trouble with this, try taking the help out an app bundle with working help and knitting it as is into your app.  This will help you get the procedure straight and give you some confidence that it can work.

Comment: I'm intrigued - because I can't get it to work no matter what I try (in Xcode 5.1). Think they don't want us to use this functionality - otherwise it would be WAAAAAY easier to setup.

The Apple documentation suggests you need to create a Bundle for your Help Book which then sits inside the Main Bundle - looks like you didn't do this and had success. Any chance you can demo it on YouTube, or upload your working demo to GitHub?

Comment: I'll get to something pretty quick and update the step by step from above.  As I can recall it was something incredibly stupid like capitalization or something like that.  Am busy but will get there within a week or two.

Comment: Great, looking forward to it! It's one of those puzzles I can't put down ;-)